# Finding the files that make up a Ruby class

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is there any way to determine which *files* were loaded and defined/modified a particular class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this correctly, but as an approximation in 1.9 you could find the `source_location` for all the methods in the class:

```
class Class
  def source_files
    methods.collect { |method_name|
      method(method_name).source_location[0] # just the filename, not the line number
    } |
    instance_methods.collect { |method_name|
      instance_method(method_name).source_location[0]
    }
  end
end
```

This will also give you the files defining methods that are inherited from the superclass or included modules, which I'm not sure whether you want. There are ways to modify a class besides defining methods in it, but this doesn't detect them, so it's not perfect.